# Discord Bot send message from udp connection to specific channel

Tags: node.js, bots, discord

I have a node.js discord bot running on my server. The bot runs a simple udp server and receives text messages from a program running a udp client. I am able to see the message in the console, but I want my bot to post the text to a channel and I can't figure out how to get the bot to post text without it being a response to user input. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');

    var dgram = require('dgram');
    var server = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

    server.on('listening', function() {
      var address = server.address();
     console.log('UDP Server listening on ' + address.address + ':' + address.port);
    });

    server.on('message', function(msg, remote) {
     console.log(`${msg}`);
    });

    server.bind(PORT, HOST);
    //END UDP Server
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you want to log all messages to a specific channel, in a specific guild, you can do so by finding the guild in the client's (server in your case) guilds collection and then finding the channel from the channels collection of that guild.

You'd need to use `server.guilds.cache.get(guild_ID).channels.cache.get(channel_ID).send(msg)` Make sure to replace `guild_ID` and `channel_ID` with the appropriate IDs.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.  I tried this code as posted and it failed: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined at Object.` does guild_ID and channel_ID need to be replaced with actual ID's or is this a variable that should be passed by the bot? If the ID's need to be provided, where do you find them? I have not been able to find any refference to ID's.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified, yes you need to replace them with actual IDs, write them in as string btw.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance. I am still having a problem with get(). Assume my guild is "My Guild" and the channel is "my-channel" how would the code look?

Comment: No, those are the guild and channel names, not their IDs, follow this guide: https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/206346498-Where-can-I-find-my-User-Server-Message-ID-

Comment: OK. Thanks. I found the id's. I have tried them inside the function both with and without " " and I still get the same error about get being undefined object.

Comment: That's my fault, I edited the answer, that should work now

Comment: Still getting an error. Here is what my code looks like. x's replaced with id #'s of course `server.guilds.cache.get("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx").channels.cache.get("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx").send(msg)` the new error is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous>`

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: Discord.js 12.1.1

Comment: Why are you using `server.on('message')` instead of `bot.on('message')`?

Comment: server.on was code I found to set up a udp server. I figured it needed to be different than the bot.on since it was connecting to something else. Still trying to muddle through learning how all these pieces fit together.

Comment: Can you try `bot.on('message')` instead?

Comment: I did just try `bot.guilds.cache.get("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx").channels.cache.get("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx").send(msg)` and got an error regarding channels this time

Comment: just `bot.on('message')` with not channel or guid id's

Comment: no I mean try `bot.on('message', function(msg) {
     console.log(msg);
    });` instead. not yet though, the error you got about the channels could be helpful

Comment: That did not throw an error, but it did not send a message to the discord server though. I still see the message in the terminal but it doesn't get sent in the discord server.

Comment: yeah, that's because you didn't tell it to, you'd do that by adding `message.channel.send(msg)` or `message.channel.send("Hello!")`

Comment: `message.channel.send()` throws error `ReferenceError: message is not defined`

Comment: oh sorry you have it set to `msg`

Comment: I just can get the ${msg} from here that prints in the terminal `server.on('message', function(msg, remote) {
     console.log(`${msg}`);
    });` to get sent into the discord server on a specific channel

Comment: I tried that too...same error with msg instead of message

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I went back and tried it again this time moving your piece of code inside the server.on function and changed your code from server.guilds to bot.guilds and I finally got it to work.